# how to get a blinking cursor instead of a selection

Tags: jquery, readonly

```js
$('.inptitle').dblclick(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).attr('readonly', false).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='inptitle' value = 'TITLE' readonly = true>
```

after `readonly` is removed I need a blinking cursor at the end of input's content and not a selection.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to take the focus away and put it back *after* the browser had time to process the read-only change and additional change of that focus. That will take care of the blinking.

To have an empty selection, you could briefly change the text and put the original back immediately.

Here is how that would look:

```js
$('.inptitle').dblclick(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr('readonly', false).blur();
    setTimeout(function () { 
        $('.inptitle').focus().val(val+" ").val(val);
    }, 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='inptitle' value = 'TITLE' readonly = true>
```

#### Observation

I would not advise to change the default behaviour: when you double click a text it is standard behaviour that the word you click on is selected. Changing this behaviour will be surprising for users and break the intuition they have.

Comment: ugh... there should be a `natural` solution, I suppose